# WP post__not_in another query not filter

Tags: php, wordpress

my first query is okay

```
$ids = [];

$novidades = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'meta_key' => 'meta-checkbox',
        'meta_value' => 'yes'
    ) );
if ( count( $novidades ) ) {
        foreach( $novidades as $novidade ) {
        $ids[] =  $novidade->ID;        
    }
}
//rest of my code is ok
```

but, i try post another post and ignore the first query, but don't work, list all post

```
$args2 = array(
'post_type'    => 'post',
'posts__not_in' => $ids     
);

$featured = new WP_Query($args2);
```

Can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `post__not_in`. Remove the extra `s` from your code.

> `post__not_in` (array) - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve. If this is used in the same query as `post__in`, it will be ignored.

Your code should be:

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'post__not_in' => $ids,//<====extra 's' removed
);

$featured = new WP_Query($args2);
```